# PHP Specify what account to choose to create transaction and then transact it to it

Tags: php

I currently have a dropdown list of 3 accounts set for users to select to send funds to.
As I have more than 3 users, could someone tell me how could I make users to input the "account number" within a 4th option?

Current code looks like this:

```php
<optgroup label="Accounts">
@foreach ($accounts as $account)
    <option value="{{ $account->id }}">{{ $account->name }} - ${{ number_format($account->money, 2) }}</option>
    <option value="895"> Blackbird - Wonderland</option> 
    <option value="902"> Nando - The Gold Reserve</option> 
step="any" min="0"></optgroup>

@endforeach
</optgroup>
```

So basically I want the user to be able to enter that "ID" and let that be used to send the funds to.

I also have a code that works but I'm not sure how to correctly put them together.

Here's something that could be tried but idk where to put it within that code:

```php
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="oaccount" value="0" step="any" min="0">
```

This is how it currently looks like: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yt6nd.png)